# TabPanel header text is blue

Tags: asp.net, ajax, tabpanel

I just updated from ASP.NET Ajax 1.0 to 4, and now the `HeaderText` in all my TabPanels is blue. I tried setting the `ForeColor` and the `Color` properties, but no luck.

How do I change my `HeaderText` back to black?

Comment: are you sure you are not using any CssClass or a default theme?Themes are generally given on the top of the page.

Comment: No themes or CssClass applied. And certainly nothing changed to blue since I updated Fri, and it was black before the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to page header: `a.ajax__tab_tab{ color: #000 !important; }`

Comment: That made the tab image disappear, and all that was showing was blue text.

Comment: Which tab image you mean? Do iy use tabs from ajax control toolkit?

Comment: Yes, these are the toolkit tabs. When I tried your code it no longer showed any image at all. It no longer looked like tabs, just a bunch of words.

Comment: are you kidding? it's just a css rule for hyperlinks color in tab header. Show your code.

Comment: Figured out what went wrong. I had set CssClass of the TabContainer. That's what was getting rid of the images. Got rid of that, and just had your code in my style sheet, with a reference to my style sheet in my master page, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @thchaver yeah just like I told ya.

Comment: @OkayGuy I didn't have any css applied to it until I tried Yuriy's code.